# Cannondale Ai (Asymmetric Integration) - on what bike models?

Tags: wheels, cannondale

I just recently heard about Cannondale AI "dishing". What documentation I found is [this](https://cannondale.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/219101107-Ai-Asymmetric-Integration-).

-Is it only cross and mtb models that use the AI system? I own several Cannondale bikes (CAAD9, 2010 Flash MTB, 2021 Synapse Carbon disc) and want to make sure what type of dishing are used on my bikes.

Comment: Not only cross and MTB. My 2020 Cannondale Synapse Neo EQ electric road bike uses Ai wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the Topstone Carbon, it was a mountain only thing. Now it's most of the nicer mountain bikes plus Topstone Carbon.

Note that there are two different generations of Ai offset; 142 and 148/Boost bikes use different offset values. The old version of the true stand/dish stick adapter tool doesn't work with 148, which is one potential source of confusion. The tool is kind of worthless anyway; you can do the same thing by poking the long end of a 3 or 6mm L-wrench into the axle when you hit it with the dish stick, and if you use an auto-centering truing stand you can just pull one side off and lock it with a rubber band etc and then true one side at a time and flip.

On mountain bikes there's rarely if ever an issue taking an off-the-shelf wheels and redishing. That changed completely now that Topstone Carbon uses it and therefore people want to plug in off-the-shelf road wheels. Wheels with 1.5mm center section spokes or 2.3mm aero spokes (Aerolites and CX-Rays) are at risk of becoming the wrong length by too much when you do the correction, because spokes that thin elongate more for a given change in tension, so it is now possible to grab a higher end prefab road wheel, try to dish it for a Topstone Carbon, and have the spokes run out of threaded length. That is the biggest potential gotcha of the whole conversation. Wheels with money spokes need to have the initial calculation done with the right values.

I don't think any model years of Flash have it, but I could be mistaken on that since it was around a while. Most bikes that do have it have stickers that say, and that notwithstanding you can just check the dish of your wheel, i.e. flip it in the bike (carefully keeping the rotor away from anything greasy) and see if the tire clearances are the same.

Answer (score 3):

To provide a little extra, the Ai dish was not introduced until around 2017.

The CAAD9 is a 2008 bike and the Flash a 2010, so these are normal symmetrical dish rear wheels.

The Synapse is quite a classic road bike and is still symmetrical but if you buy one of the better Cannondale MTB from 2017 on, it could easily be Ai spaced.

Knutson's detailed answer provides the rest of the background you need.